# force rowspan not to split other column data in new page

Tags: css, joomla

Currently i'm working on attendance report generation but now i face this problem i try every css print property but nothing works for me below the css code that i use

```
#printdata h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
text-align: center;
line-height: 0.1em;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#printdata p{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#printdata table {
    margin-top: 10px; 
    page-break-after:auto; 
    width:100% 
}

#printdata tr{ 
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    -webkit-region-break-inside: avoid; 
}  


#printdata td{ 
    page-break-inside:avoid; 
    page-break-after:auto; 
    padding: 16px 0px; 
    font-size: 12pt; 
}

thead{ 
    display:table-header-group; 
}

tfoot{ 
    display:table-footer-group; 
}
```

Here my php code where i use rowspan on column 1 and 2

```
<tbody>
        <?
            if(count($this->employees) > 0)
            {
                $x = 0;
                foreach ($this->employees as $key=>$employee)
                {    
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2"><? echo ++$x; ?></td>
                        <td rowspan="2" align="center"><? echo $employee->ticket_no; ?></td>
                        <td colspan="2"><? echo $employee->employee_name; ?></td>
                        <?
                            for($i=1;$i<=$days_in_month;$i++)
                            {
                                ?>
                                <td  align="center">
                                    <?
                                        if($employee->in_time[$i] == "" && $employee->out_time[$i] == "" && $employee->minutes_late[$i] == "" && $employee->gate_pass[$i] == "" && $employee->idle_booking[$i] == "" && $employee->minutes_early[$i] == "" && $employee->second_half_cl[$i] == "")
                                        {
                                            echo $employee->attendance[$i];
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            echo $employee->in_time[$i];
                                            echo ($employee->out_time[$i] != "" ? $employee->out_time[$i] : "");
                                            //echo ($employee->attendance[$i] != "" ? $employee->attendance[$i] : "");
                                            echo ($employee->minutes_late[$i] != "" ? $employee->minutes_late[$i] : "");
                                            echo ($employee->gate_pass[$i] != "" ? ($employee->minutes_late[$i] != "" ? " + " : "") . $employee->gate_pass[$i] : "");
                                            echo ($employee->idle_booking[$i] != "" ? $employee->idle_booking[$i] : "");
                                            echo ($employee->minutes_early[$i] != "" ? $employee->minutes_early[$i] : "");
                                            echo ($employee->second_half_cl[$i] != "" ? $employee->second_half_cl[$i] : "");
                                            //echo ($this->leaves[$i] != "" ? $employee->second_half_cl[$i] : "");
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                                <?
                            }
                        ?>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center">A</td>
                        <td align="center">B</td>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center">C</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><? echo $employee->section; ?></td>
                        <td><? echo $employee->trade; ?></td>
                        <? 
                        for($i=1;$i<=$days_in_month;$i++)
                            {
                                echo "<td align='center'>";
                                echo $i;
                                echo "</td>";
                            }
                        ?>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">2</td>
                        <td align="center">3</td>
                        <td align="center">4</td>
                        <td align="center">5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <? 
                }
            } 
        ?
</tbody>
```

This is the result basically i get i just want to forcefully stop spliting rowspan in new page it would be great is its avoid split and print the whole row in new page

For better understanding check below image and any help would be appriciated
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvkF5.png

Comment: Hi Ankur, did you find any work around? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if this works?

```
printdata table { page-break-inside:auto }
printdata table tr { page-break-inside:avoid; 
                     page-break-after:auto }
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting but this doesn't work i still face the same problem on row 23 my row split :(